# Prove that $inf\ \{|x_n|, n \in \mathbb{N}\}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_n≠0,  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose there are $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0<|x_{n+1}|<c|x_n|<|x_n|$

I need to prove that $inf\ \{|x_n|, n \in \mathbb{N}\}=0$

My attempt:

Suppose there exists $0^*>0$ such that $0^*<|x_n|$. Note that $c \in (0,1)$ and $c\cdot 0^* \in \mathbb{R}^+\  \land \ c\cdot 0^*<0^* \implies$ $0^*$ can't be the largest of the lower bounds, so $inf\ \{|x_n|, n \in \mathbb{N}\}=0$

I did it well?

Comment: Why does $c \cdot 0^* < 0^*$ matter?  It seems to me you need to relate this to the sequence $x_n$ more closely. (Also, as a typographic note, $0^*$ is not a nice notation)

Comment: On what basis do you say $0^*$ can't be the largest of the lower bound? You did not find  a lower bound which is larger than $0^*$.

Comment: oh, you're right i just did it all wrong hahahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $\{|x_{n}|\}$ is monotonic decreasing. as from the given condition $|x_{n+1}|<|x_{n}|$ . I would assume without loss of generality that $|x_{1}|>0$. If not then we could take the infimimum $n$ such that $|x_{n}|>0$ and repeat the proof which I did. If such an $n$ does not exist then we have a zero sequence and there is nothing to prove.

$|x_{2}|<c_{1}|x_{1}|$ .

$|x_{3}|<c_{2}|x_{2}|$

Now let $c'_{2}=\max\{c_{1}, c_{2}\}$.

Then $|x_{3}|<c'_{2}|x_{2}|<(c'_{2})^{2}|x_{1}|$

Call this $c'_{2}$ as $c_{2}$.

So proceeding inductively there is exist a $c_{n}\in(0,1)$ such that

$|x_{n+1}|<(c_{n})^{n}|x_{n}|<(c_{n})^{n}|x_{1}|$

Now consider the sequence $(c_{n})^{n}|x_{1}|$. This has a subsequence which converge to $0$. call it $\{(c_{n_{k}})^{n_{k}}|x_{1}|\}$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

Then for  $M\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $(c_{n_{k}})^{n_{k}}|x_{1}|<\epsilon\,\,\forall k\geq M$

So correspondingly we have $|x_{n_{k}+1}|<(c_{n_{k}})^{n_{k}}|x_{1}|<\epsilon$.

So $0$ is the greatest lower bound as any lower bound greater than $0$ fails to be an upper bound.

So $\inf\{|x_{n}|:n\in\mathbb{N}\}=0$